# sprintf causes undefined behaviour

Tags: c, printf

The questions are in the comments.

Something undefined is happening because of the sprintf function. 
Plus the buffer[0] = 0xff statement has to be placed after the fopen command, otherwise an error occurs. I dont know why that happens either. Could anyone please point out whats wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//unsinged int of size 1 byte
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;

int main() {

    // open memory card file
    FILE* memcard = fopen("card.raw","r");

    BYTE buffer [512];
    char name [7];
    int n = 0;

    // open a file to store the initial garbage in card.raw
    FILE*file = fopen("useless.txt","w");

    // read blocks from card.raw till fread doesnt read anything
    while(fread(buffer, 1, 512, memcard)!= 0) {

        //check the first four bytes for jpeg signature
        if((buffer[0] == 0xff) &&(buffer[1] == 0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff) && ((buffer[3] == 0xe0) || (buffer[3] == 0xe1))) { 
            fclose(file);

            printf("%x b\n", buffer[0]);
            //output is "ff b" 
            sprintf(name,"%03d.jpg",n);
            printf("%x a\n", buffer[0]);
            //output is "0 a"

            // somehow the sprintf function changes the value of buffer[0] 

            file = fopen(name,"w"); 

            //buffer[0] = 0xff which reassing 0x ff to buffer[0] has to come after the fopen command, otherwise this happens
            //001.jpg  (invalid encoding), but the value of buffer[0] remains the same 0xff
            buffer[0] = 0xff;
            n++;

            printf("%x \n", buffer[0]);     
        }       

        //write 512 bytes into the open file
        fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, file);    
    }

    fclose(file);

    if(feof(memcard))
        printf("End of file\n");

    fclose(memcard);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char name[7]` is not large enough to accommodate `"%03d.jpg\0"`.

Everything that happens after `sprintf(name,"%03d.jpg",n)` is a matter of chance.

Answer (score 2):

You're suffering the catastrophic events of a classic buffer overflow. You declared `char name[7]`, but you need exactly 8 bytes to store "%03d.jpg". The `sprintf` function automatically appends the `NULL` (`\0`) byte to the end of the string. Be cautious!

```
123.jpg\0
```

Comment: thank you so much. Now that I've changed the the length of name to 8, everything is normal again.